# Grails 2.3.7+ reloading non-forked execution not working

Tags: grails

Since Grails 2.3.7 (at least, this is my first encounter) reloading stop working ootb when running non-forked development mode. That is:

```
grails.project.fork = [
    compile: false,
    test: false,
    run: false,
    war: false,
    console: false
]
```

However. I found a solution that fixed the problem:

1. Setting `grails.reload.enabled  = true`
2. Starting with: `grails run-app -reloading`
3. Copying `grails-2.3.x\lib\org.springsource.springloaded` to `grails-2.3.7\lib\org.springsource.springloaded`

I actually thought this was a bug in the 2.3.7 version. However I just started a new project with 2.4.0 - and it is the same issue. I solved it again with the above solution, but I'm not sure of the consequences since Grails 2.4 is using Spring 4 (maybe a new "spring-loaded" version should be used?).

My question is: What is the proper solution to this problem? (Running forked is not an answer!)

Am I the only one experiencing this?

Comment: no you are not.  i added this for running non-forked in intellij, but it it does not work 100% like the regular reloading ``-javaagent:${GRAILS_HOME}/lib/org.springframework/springloaded/jars/springloaded-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar -Xverify:none  -noverify -Dspringloaded.synchronize=true -Djdk.reflect.allowGetCallerClass=true -Dspringloaded=profile=grails;cacheDir=/tmp/slcache``

Comment: But that is just plain stupid. It worked so beautiful before...

Comment: "Running forked is not an answer" - what is the issue with running forked? What problems do you face that prevents you from using forked only mode?

Non-forked mode is essentially deprecated and will be removed in Grails 3.0

Comment: Is debugging in IntelliJ 13 (without using remote debugging) possible with 2.4.0? (Haven't tried). That's been my issue with forked so far. And please don't ask why "without remote debugging".

Comment: @GraemeRocher non-forked simply was the sweet spot on my project where debugging and everything else worked with least effort (call me lazy).  e.g. with vaadin the sass compiler runs in classloader issues with forked exec (i assume no grails problem). so if non-forked is deprecated, it should tell the user (warn on run-app, put it in documentation) -- especially if reloading with current (2.3 and 2.4) versions is not working at all with the ``-reloading`` switch from the documentation.

Comment: @GraemeRocher any response?

Comment: @GraemeRocher - can you please comment? I am now running forked - as it is issentially deprecated (?!) - and using a remote debugger. Everything is now twice as tedious and twice as annoyning when developing. Why was non-forked with reloading during development such a bad idea again? I'm so tired of this situation. And the fact that you are removing the option for reloading without stating it anywhere - whats that about?? (I'm thinking it's because you know it's a bad idea, and you know that many many developers are just like cfrick and me!)

Comment: Again you have yet to explain why it is "twice as annoying" and "twice as tedious". What are the issues that make it so? Instead of spouting random nonsense without presenting facts please do something useful like create  JIRA issue with the behaviour that you see as problematic.

Comment: Seems impossible to get reasons of you, creating a JIRA - even though it probably will be closed with "Not a bug" instantly.